# Failed to reduce match type in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-3, match-types

I'm hacking match types in Scala 3, and would like to define such match type that any `Either[A, B]` would be reassociated to be right-side recursive, i.e.:

```scala
Rebalance[(Int Either String) Either (Boolean Either Long)] =:= (Int Either (String Either (Boolean Either Long)))
```

I've assembled the following piece of code (also [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/sergeykolbasov/yThNmeceSCmPNP0jAZBaFQ/37)):

```scala
type Rebalance[A] = A match {
  case Either[Either[a, b], c] => Rebalance[Either[a, Either[b, c]]]
  case Either[a, Either[b, c]] => Either[a, Rebalance[Either[b, c]]]
  case Either[a, b]            => Either[a, b]
}

type RebalancePair[A, B] = (A, B) match {
  case (Either[a, b], c) => RebalancePair[a, Either[b, c]]
  case (a, Either[b, c]) => Either[a, RebalancePair[b, c]]
  case (a, b) => Either[a, b]
}

type RebalanceProxy[A] = A match {
  case Either[a, b] => RebalancePair[a, b]
}

type Balanced = Int Either (String Either (Boolean Either Long))

summon[RebalanceProxy[(Int Either String) Either (Boolean Either Long)] =:= Balanced] //this works
summon[Rebalance[(Int Either String) Either (Boolean Either Long)] =:= Balanced] //this doesn't

^^^ 

Cannot prove that Playground.Rebalance[Either[Int, Either[String, Either[Boolean, Long]]]] =:= Playground.Balanced.

Note: a match type could not be fully reduced:

  trying to reduce  Playground.Rebalance[Either[Int, Either[String, Either[Boolean, Long]]]]
  failed since selector  Either[Int, Either[String, Either[Boolean, Long]]]
  does not match  case Either[Either[a, b], c] => Playground.Rebalance[Either[a, Either[b, c]]]
  and cannot be shown to be disjoint from it either.
  Therefore, reduction cannot advance to the remaining cases

    case Either[a, Either[b, c]] => Either[a, Playground.Rebalance[Either[b, c]]]
    case Either[a, b] => Either[a, b]
​
```

I'm curious why it works via `RebalanceProxy` & `RebalancePair` match, and yet fails with visibly the same match type `Rebalance`? The reason I'd like to achieve it directly via `Rebalance` is that it would be quite simple to define a dependently typed function for `Rebalance`, but not for a `RebalancePair`.